# Grails Log4J File appender not writing to file

Tags: grails, log4j

I can't seem to get a log4j file appender to write to a file in a grails app.  The file is getting created in the directory I expect, when running in debug mode I can see that the log method is being called, but still no results in the file.  Appender code and log code below.  I have made my log4j config as simple as possible to root out any complex issues.  Ideas?

```
abstract class BaseJob {

abstract def executeTask()
def execute() {
    beginTask()
    executeTask()
    endTask()
}
def beginTask()
{
    log.error("Started task: " + this.class)
}
def endTask()
{
    log.error("Finished task: " + this.class)
}
}

log4j = {
// Example of changing the log pattern for the default console
// appender:
//
appenders {
    //console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
    file name:'myLogger', file:"all.log", immediateFlush:'true', threshold:org.apache.log4j.Level.DEBUG

}

debug 'grails.app'
```

}

Answer (score 3):

according to documentation http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/conf.html#logging
you have to use:

```
debug myLogger: 'grails.app'
```

or for several loggers

```
debug myLogger: ['grails.app', 'org.apache']
```

works on grails 2.0.4